# Unexpected combination of states REMOVED, CHANGED for file build/intermediates/java_res/flav/out/META_INF/shared_flav.kotlin_module

Tags: android-studio

full error: Unexpected combination of states REMOVED, CHANGED for file /Users/StudioProject/Project/Module/shared/build/intermediates/java_res/flav/out/META_INF/shared_flav.kotlin_module

this error occurred for me in android studio in our production project (preventing any builds) for some random module (not modified recently), haven't found any posts covering it, thus the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

steps to fix:

1. file -> sync project with gradle files
2. build -> clean project
3. file -> invalidate caches and restart (sometimes optional)

expected the problem to disappear after doing the step 3 alone, but it did not ;-;

Comment: Please leave answers for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information by clicking the "edit" button.

Comment: @Fastnlight: I think this _is_ an answer, just a bit clumsy in the wording. Specifically, I think it’s saying: “these steps together work, even if I’d have expected only the last step to be required”.